# Routing behaving weirdly

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.EnableQuerySupport();
    }
}
```

My controller file is:

```
namespace myApp.Data
{
  public class AccountController : ApiController
  {
    public List<User> XGetUsers()
    {
        List<User> Users;
        using (Entities db = new Entities())
        {
            var users = from u in db.Users select u;
            Users = users.ToList();
        }
        return Users;
    }

    // GET api/<controller>/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
  }
}
```

But whenever I tried to call localhost:51255/api/Account/XGetUsers I keep getting a 400 error:

> {"Message":"The request is invalid.","MessageDetail":"The parameters
>   dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable
>   type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.String Get(Int32)' in
>   myApp.Data.AccountController'. An optional parameter must be a
>   reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional
>   parameter."}

It seems that all calls are going to the method Get(int id).  What is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your route is missing the action:

```
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
```

so it was thinking that `{id}` was `XGetUsers`.

Comment: @OldGeezer, no worries, I'm glad I could be of assistance!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to only have defined one possibility: That the part after the controller is an id. There is only one action that matches that, therefore that action is the only candidate to be invoked.

Perhaps you want to also add an `"api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"` to match your other candidates.